# show that if p is a prime divisor of $839$ and $(5/p)=1$ then $839$ is a prime number

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Show that if p is a prime divisor of $839$ = $38^2$ - $5*11^2$ then $(5/p)=1$. Use this fact to conclude that $839$ is a prime number.

Comment: If $p|839$ how is $839$ a prime number

Comment: Well...you could use quadratic reciprocity to note that $\left( \frac 5p \right)=1\implies p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$ (well, for odd $p$ at least) and this reduces the search for prime factors.  On the other hand, establishing the primality of $839$ is trivial without all that fuss.

Comment: $839$ is a prime number. What do you mean by $(5/p)≡ 1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse engineering the hint the best I can:

- We have $839=38^2-5\cdot11^2$. So if $p$ is any prime divisor of $839$, then $$5\cdot11^2\equiv38^2\pmod p.$$ This implies that $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.
- By quadratic reciprocity $p$ is then a quadratic residue modulo $5$. In other words $p\equiv\pm1\pmod5$.
- The only primes $<\sqrt{839}$ and $\equiv\pm1\pmod5$ are $11$ and $19$. If $839$ were not a prime it would have a prime factor less than $\sqrt{839}$. But neither $11$ nor $19$ works (see Daniel's comment below!), so such a prime does not exist.
- Conclusion: $839$ is a prime.

In other words, my guess is that the hint is supposed to help you sieve out some of the candidate prime factors with a view of speeding up the verification that $839$ is a prime.

Comment: In particular, since in $839 = 38^2 - 5\cdot 11^2$, one term is evidently divisible by $11$, and not by $19$, while the other term is easily seen to be a multiple of $19$ but not divisible by $11$. So we don't need to do the "hard work" of checking whether $11$ or $19$ divide $839$ the brute-force way.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $\sqrt{839} \sim 28.9$, it suffices to consider cases for those prime numbers less than $29$. All primes less than $29$ are: $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23$ none of which divide $839$. Hence, it is prime.